# THREE.js - Texture mapping requirements

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

**Intro**

I have a web service that returns a json result that contains an image path.
These images are not necessarily square images (e.g. 200px x 250px).

**Problem**

It seems non-square images are not supported for texture mapping. In order for the texture mapping to work I have to manually download the image, resize it, and use that image for the texture mapping (and it works).

**Questions**

A) Could there be a way to make three.js/webgl use non-square images for texture mapping?

B) Could there be a way to programmatically load & resize an image and subsequently load it for texture mapping?

Thanks all.

**Possible Solution?**

I found what could be a viable option. Let me know what you guys think of this.

Basically, I will load the remote image and draw to a Canvas element which is square in size. Then I can get the image from the canvas (.getImageData) and save it to my web server's image folder (if this cant be done then I can just keep the image on the canvas). Finally, load the image for texture mapping.

I know this is pretty vague and simplistic. But hey, simpler the better, right?
Will this work?

Comment: three.js does support non square textures with no special treatment: http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/MZpx8/

Comment: @gaitat. I don't understand. this example uses a .jpg which is a square.

Comment: no its not a square; its size is 1280x1202

Answer (score 1):

DON'T resize it in a non-conformal manner, just take a square section (e.g., if the image is 250 X 220, just chop out a 220 X 220 sub-image).  The texture classification algorithm may very well depend upon angles and related features that your skew-by-resize may short-circuit.

Comment: Well, in my case, the images are floorplans. So I can't take a sub-image. Rather, I resize "upward". What do you mean by "non-conformal manner"? And, what is this "texture classification algorithm"?

Comment: And by the way, I do not skew-by-resize, whatever that means. I just resize the canvas. I do not do any kind of skewing or stretching or scaling.